# How to classify imbalanced data in weka?

Tags: python, weka

I have an imbalanced training data and i am using logistic regression in weka to classify.

> There are two classes good and bad. Good has 75000 instances and bad
>   3000.  My test data has 10000 good data.

When i train it is more inclined to good data i.e it classifies almost all bad instances good. What should i do ?
I tried to have 10000 good instances in training data instead of 75000 but still the problem is same.

Comment: difficult to tell without any info. do you still have an anonymous unique identifier in your dataset? if so, remove that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about python but in the gui version you can use SpreadSubsample to reduce the class imbalance. If you feel that 'bad' is a a good representation of the class then you could experiment with different number of instances of 'good.'

To do this you need to select Filter ==> Supervised ==> Instance ==> SpreadSubsample ==> change the number of instances using 'max count'

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that you could try.

1. Use Boosting (AdaBoostM1) so that the misclassified instances will be given extra weight.
2. Use weka.classifiers.meta.CostSensitiveClassifier    and give the "bad" instances a higher weight than the "good" instances.   **Note**: This will probably reduce your overall accuracy, but make your classifier do a better job of identifying the "bad" instances.